# Integrate Radioactivity with Apache Solr (sort by popularity)

Tags: search

Has anyone integrated integrated [Radioactivity](http://drupal.org/project/radioactivity) with Apache Solr?

I'm using the [apachesolr](http://drupal.org/project/apachesolr) module for search and would like to add the ability to sort by popularity. The Radioactivity module assigns points to a module based on 'hotness' (fivestar ratings, comments, views, etc). I want to submit the points Radioactivity gives a node to Solr to use as a popularity index.

I believe that means I'll need to modify the schema.xml file on the Solr end and add some sort of hook on the drupal end. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this without modifying `schema.xml`. At a minimum, you'll need to implement `hook_apachesolr_update_index()`, and you may also need to implement `hook_apachesolr_modify_query()` to add the Radioactivity data to each query.

Good examples for this can be found in the apachesolr_search.module file itself (and the apachesolr_date module that comes bundled with apachesolr), and also in the additional contrib modules [apachesolr OG](http://drupal.org/project/apachesolr_og) and [apachesolr attachments](http://drupal.org/project/apachesolr_attachments).

The apachesolr_date module in particular has some code related to adding an available sort option.

Comment: Would this work possibly? http://drupal.org/node/715276