# Display Ubercart sell price in Apache Solr search results

Tags: 6, search

I manage an ubercart store that is indexed by Apache Solr. The search indexes the sell price and it's one of the facets. However, the price is nowhere in search-result.tpl.php. It's also not available in the search results preprocess hook in template.php. Is there somewhere else I can inject it into the search results without performing a separate database query for each search result.

Answer (score 1):

You can index it using solr's dynamic fields (see your schema.xml in the solr conf directory) and a custom module hook, namely `hook_apachesolr_update_index()`.

Then you can, at search time, add the field you have indexed into the fields being fetched. For this you have three hooks or 'hooks' to choose from: `hook_apachesolr_prepare_query()`, `hook_apachesolr_modify_query()` and `CALLER_finalize_query()`.

For further information on the hooks, see the **README.txt** in the apachesolr module directory.

Then in your **search-result.tpl.php** you'll have available the custom indexed field as `$result['fields']['your_field_name']`.

Comment: Just discovered that  http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/5088/5678 pretty much covers the same basics, although not the search result template.